# whichever or whatever

Tags: adjectives, singular-vs-plural

a. They told me to take whichever one I liked.

b. They told me to take whatever one I liked.

Is there any difference of the meanings of (a) and (b)?

Could (b) used instead of

c) They told me to take whichever **ones** I liked.

?

Answer (score 1):

*Which* is usually used when it's a choice between two or more items, so (a) is better with *one.*

If you were invited to take *whatever you liked* from an assorted collection of things, you could feel free to help yourself to several of them.